# Singleton Inject and Memory Allocation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, constructor-injection

I have a design that I wish to follow and it composes of 3 layers. Model, Service, Data. Typical service/repository would look like this:

```
public class ReadingService : IReadingService
{
    IReadingRepository readonly _readingRepository;
    IEnumerable<Reading> _myReadings;

    public ReadingService(IReadingRepository readingRepository)
    {
        _readingRepository = readingRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Reading> GetMyReadings()
    {
        return _myReadings ?? (_myReadings =_readingRepository.GetMyReadings());
    }
}

public class ReadingRepository : IReadingRepository
{
    IMyCustomConnection readonly _connection;

    public ReadingRepository(IMyCustomConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyReading> GetMyReadings()
    {
        var query = @"Some Query";
        return _connection.Query(query);
    }
}
```

I am going to be injecting these classes into controllers as they are needed. Mostly I will be injecting the service, `IReadingService`. The problem that I have is actually a dilemma of what scope to use when binding. If I were to use singleton scope, than my lazy loading approach works beautifully. (For sake of argument, assume `_myReadings` does not get updated very often). So in this instance I don't want to query the database every time as I have no need to.

However, the other part is, how much can I actually put in memory. What I would actually like to do is make every service and every repository class that I make a type of singleton. The reason being is so that I can implement lazy loading at any time on anything I want. Now I understand that I need to properly dispose of `IMyCustomConnection` and I have done that so that it doesn't cause issue if called multiple times in a single request.

My inexperience here is the biggest reason for hesitation. Is adding a large number of classes like this to singleton scope ok? Should I only be doing this on select few that I need? Is the memory that they use up more hurtful than just creating them on every request? Are there any other things I should consider when thinking about this approach?

Couple of side notes that might matter:
I am using MVC 5, Dapper and Autofac.

Comment: If it's a singleton you cannot dispose the connection until the end of the application, keep that in mind

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What I have done is I wrapped the IOdbConnection in a custom object. Whenever query is called, it creates a new instance of that IDbConnection and disposes of it. The wrapper object itself though is singleton. `private IDbConnection Connection => new SqlConnection("some value");` Then when code calls it: `using (var con = Connection) {}`

Comment: If you Register your service scoped, you should also can use it as long as you need it, but its not shared between queries.

Comment: why not just use a real caching mechanism like the ASP.net application cache and keep your data access layer singleton free.

Comment: your're mixing concerns by having methods to retrieve data in the same class where you store the data. You should avoid storing data in singleton classes at all costs, in addition to memory concerns you're going to run into thread safety problems.

Comment: @P.Roe Just to make sure I understand, I should avoid using singleton approach to store things such as `IEnumerable<Reading>` in the above example. But it is ok to store the service itself? If that is true, then I have to make sure my services never store local values if I want them to be singleton?

Comment: Yes you largely have it. An exception would be you can store config data in your services as long as it's a one-time write into your service's field's or properties and from then on it's a read. And then just to rephrase, any data that might change during the execution of your program after it's initial load should not be stored in a class that it implemented as a singleton or static.